# willDisplayCell delegate method Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I've been working around the `tableview` and got stuck on the following issue.

As far as i understand the `willDisplayCell` delegate method should allow me to access the current cell design.
**My issue is** - i cannot access the instance of the custom cell, because it was separately declared in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. And if i declare it again - i cannot access it's objects (i have an `uibutton` there). Or maybe i'm misunderstanding the use of this method.

Here is my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

//declaring the cell variable again

    var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

    if let text = cell.lblCarName.text where !text.isEmpty {
        cell.act1.hidden = false
    } else {
        println("Failed")
    }
}
```

My goal as it is seen in the code is to access the `TblCell uilabel` and apply a conditional to it - if its nil - show the `uibutton`.

NB: My delegate and datasource is set correctly, the method is running, the app compiles, but the conditionals don't work as i've intended them to.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering though, why can't you do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This delegate give you the instance of the cell which will now be shown and that particular cell is actually sent in as the `cell` parameter. Typecast it and use the conditional.

Try this code instead.

```
var cell:TblCell = cell as! TblCell

if let text = cell.lblCarName.text where !text.isEmpty {
    cell.act1.hidden = false
} else {
    println("Failed")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a very good idea. Tried it, but as the result uibutton becomes visible on every cell, except the last one - where the uilabel text is actually nil. Is it how it should work? Because i was expecting the opposite result (

Comment: if you just want to hide the cell.act1, you can just do that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, shouldn't you?

Comment: tried applying the same conditional in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. gives me the same result - uibutton is visible on all cells, except the last one.

Comment: and you want UIButton only to be visible if cell.lblCarName.text is not empty, right?

Comment: otherwise, i want it to be visible when cell is cell.lblCarName.text is empty

Comment: i understood the mistake) very obvious) it's quest the !text.IsEmpty criteria. Thank you

Comment: try using `if cell.lblCarName.text.isEmpty { cell.act1.hidden.false } else { cell.act1.hidden = true }`

Answer (score 4):

I think a better way would be:

```
guard let cell = cell as? TblCell else { return }
```

inside the willDisplayCell